# How To use a Grouping query

Tags: oracle

Hi Please help me out to resolve my doubt,Am getting an output like this in oracle9i,

```
S.No   Column1     Column2  Column3  DateCol

1      A            B        C        10/2001 

2      A            B        C        03/2001  

3      B            B        C        02/2001 

4      B            B        C        01/2001

5      A            B        C        03/2000
```

But My real scenario is , i need to populate the output in below structure

```
S.No   Column1     Column2  Column3  DateCol

1      A            B        C        10/2001 

       A            B        C        03/2001  

2      B            B        C        02/2001 

       B            B        C        01/2001

3      A            B        C        03/2000
```

I dont know how to form the query , to retrieve the structure, please help me out, my academic project is already over date, please anyone provide the solution for me..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE SCOTT.GROUP_SHOW_ONCE
(
  SR_NO    NUMBER,
  COL1     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  COL2     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  COL3     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  DATECOL  DATE
)

Insert into GROUP_SHOW_ONCE
   (SR_NO, COL1, COL2, COL3, DATECOL)
 Values
   (1, 'A', 'B', 'C', TO_DATE('10/11/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into GROUP_SHOW_ONCE
   (SR_NO, COL1, COL2, COL3, DATECOL)
 Values
   (2, 'A', 'B', 'C', TO_DATE('03/11/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into GROUP_SHOW_ONCE
   (SR_NO, COL1, COL2, COL3, DATECOL)
 Values
   (3, 'B', 'B', 'C', TO_DATE('02/11/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into GROUP_SHOW_ONCE
   (SR_NO, COL1, COL2, COL3, DATECOL)
 Values
   (4, 'B', 'B', 'C', TO_DATE('01/11/2012 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into GROUP_SHOW_ONCE
   (SR_NO, COL1, COL2, COL3, DATECOL)
 Values
   (5, 'A', 'B', 'C', TO_DATE('03/11/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
COMMIT;
```

---your query will like

```
SELECT DECODE (rnn, LAG (rnn) OVER (ORDER BY TO_NUMBER (rnn)), NULL, rnn) sr_no,col1, col2, col3,datecol
  FROM (SELECT   col1, col2, col3,DATECOL,
                 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY rn) rnn
            FROM (SELECT sr_no, col1, col2, col3,DATECOL,
                         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY sr_no)  rn
                    FROM group_show_once)
        ORDER BY rnn)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please don't just post code, but add some description about what it does how it solves the given problem. You can anytime [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).